# Does `Dispatch<SetStateAction<T>>` preserve order?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

We know that manipulating the state can be `async`. But what about the order of state manipulation?

Assume the following order of events:

- Manipulate state #1
- Manipulate state #2
- Manipulate state #3

Does that mean, the state ALWAYS gets manipulated in that order or can something like this happen:

- Manipulate state #1
- Manipulate state #3
- Manipulate state #2

[To make it a bit more practical, consider this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-6my243?file=/src/App.tsx):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

function NumberBra() {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState<number[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNumbers((prevNumbers) => [...prevNumbers, 1]);
    setNumbers((prevNumbers) => [...prevNumbers, 2]);
    setNumbers((prevNumbers) => [...prevNumbers, 3]);
    setNumbers((prevNumbers) => [...prevNumbers, 4]);
    setNumbers((prevNumbers) => [...prevNumbers, 5]);
  }, []);

  return <>{numbers}</>;
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <p>
        <NumberBra />
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is the output guaranteed to be `12345` or can, under some rare circumstances, also `13245` be generated?

An answer needs to explain why it works the way it works.

Comment: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#updating-the-same-state-variable-multiple-times-before-the-next-render Does this answer your question?

Comment: No, because `setNumber(n => n + 1);` is executed 3 times and the result will always be the same, no matter the order in which each `setNumber` is getting executed.

Comment: If you are not using async manipulation just sync, the queue order of state manipulations do not change. Just read the full page of the link above, there is everything.

Comment: Yes, I am a maroon. Docs state "setNumber(n => n + 1): n => n + 1 is a function. React adds it to a queue." This is what I was looking for, so Dennis feel free to post this as an answer and I will gladly accept it. And sorry again. ;)